# How can I use the IsGranted annotation with a string as subject?

Tags: symfony, annotations

I find it really handy that in Symfony I can use annotations to add extra functionality to my controller methods in a clean way. Like this for example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}")
 * @IsGranted("view", subject="product")
 * @return Response
 */
public function view(Product $product)
{
    dump(compact('product'));

    return new Response('It worked!');
}
```

However, for the create method, I don't have a product instance, so I'd like to use the `@IsGranted` annotation with as the subject the string "App\Entity\Post". I hoped I could do that like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @IsGranted("create", subject=Product::class)
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return new Response('Did it work?');
}
```

But unfortunately I get the following error: `Could not find the subject "App\Entity\Product" for the @IsGranted annotation. Try adding a "$App\Entity\Product" argument to your controller method.`

So `@IsGranted` is still under the impression that it's supposed to look for a method parameter with the name `$App\Entity\Product`. Is there a way I can use it with just a string literal?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just omit the subject attribute?

I haven't used the annotation but I know that Symfony auth checker allows to call "isGranted" without a subject.

See example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code

Comment: I know, but my voters needs to have the entity's FQCN to know what to vote.

Comment: Well then, I would manually instanciate the object and make the isGranted call in the controller (instead of using annotation). I couldn't find documentation in Symfony about an IsGranted annotation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html), where does yours come from?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html

Comment: "Use it to restrict by roles, or use custom voters to restrict access based on variables passed to the controller", as I said perform the check manually by passing an instance of your subject or modify your voter so it accepts voting on "create" attribute without a subject (which makes sense to me as the question would be "can current user create A product" instead of "can current user create THIS product (which hasn't been created yet => paradox detected)".

Comment: But then how does the voter know if I'm asking about creating a product and not creating something else? ;-) That's why I wanted to add the FQCN as the subject, but not an instance of course. But yeah okay, I'll just code it in the method itself.

Comment: You could also change the attribute into CREATE_PRODUCT or base your security strategy on roles (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CREATOR or whatever fit your domain model). However you cannot pass something else than an object or null to the Authorization Checker (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/9f1c017983a281ad4f29b8681fda1530d4e750c1/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManagerInterface.php).

Answer (score 2):

This is old post, but this is how you could have accomplished it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", defaults={"my_variable": "my_string"})
 * @IsGranted("MY_VOTER", subject="my_variable")
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
class AnotherController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('MY_VOTER', 'my_variable');

        //...

    }
}
```

unlike the 'IsGranted' annotation, method 'denyAccessUnlessGranted' takes string easier ;)